# Why audio didn't play's on click?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating a drum machine app. I can't find a method to play audio on pressing a button so I tried it my self. I created a separate method that returns audio element with source of audio file. I call that method on clicking a button but I can't hear any audio.
Here is the code:

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
            this.clicker=this.clicker.bind(this);

 }
  clicker(){
  return(
    <audio autoplay>
    <source src="./1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
   )
 }

render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <input type="button" onClick={this.clicker} value="play">
    </input>
  </div>
  );
  }
 }
```

is my approach correct to creating a drum machine or is there any better way? any further help will be appreciated.. Thanks..

Comment: I assume you need to add the audio element to the DOM before it starts playing.

Comment: Becuase your click handler is returning HTML not playing the mp3, put your audio tag in the document, find it and call play on it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your audio player to the DOM then call play on it, here is a quick example.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.clicker=this.clicker.bind(this);
  }
 }

render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <input type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('myAudioPlayer').play()" value="play">
    </input>
  </div>
  <audio autoplay id="myAudioPlayer">
    <source src="./1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
  );
  }
 }
```

Comment: Well with the little information you provided I can't offer any help. Maybe check the console to see if there was an error. Was the audio element rendered on the screen? Just saying "it didn't work" does not give me the opportunity to help you.

Comment: Dude you are adding a string as a event listener...It say's "Expected onClick listener to be a function..."

Comment: After wraping it in curly brackets instead of quotes, it say's cannot read property "play" of null... then wrapped it in a arrow function now I get no errors but there is no audio on pressing the button....

Comment: @BilalKazmi lol, its a click handler on an element, it has to be a string.

Comment: @BilalKazmi either way the principal stays the same, you just find the element then call play on it.

Comment: @BilalKazmi create an event handler for the click of the link, in that event handler find the element you rendered on the page and call play on it. That's what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a little research and reading this [HTML5 audio is not playing in my React app in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121471/html5-audio-is-not-playing-in-my-react-app-in-localhost) I get to know that you have to import mp3 files before using them as **import mp3_file from {{filename}}**. Then you can use them and it works.... Perfect!!